# How to define the input array for RNA training in the rnn package?

Tags: r, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In the package rnn there is an example of how to carry out the training of the network, which is described in this link (example 1). In the approach of this package the inputs are given in the format of a 3D array, where the dim 1: samples; Dim 2: time; Dim 3: variables, however not making explicit the division of inputs and targets (inputs and targets, which is a common approach in RNA packages). Moreover, in the package description both the entries and the targets must have the same dimension. So, how can I define my dataset for the recurrent neural network in the rnn package? [Data to a reproductive example.](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/files/1220978/data_ex_git.zip)

My train data (inputs) on DF, first five rows:

```
> data[1:5,2:14]
           Ibiara.P_t Ibiara.P_t_1 Ibiara.P_t_2 Nova.Olinda.P_t_1 Princesa.Isabel.P_t_1 Boa.ventura.P_t_1 Boa.Ventura.P_t_2
1966-01-01          0            0            0                 0                     0                 0                 0
1966-01-02          0            0            0                 0                     0                 0                 0
1966-01-03          0            0            0                 0                     0                 0                 0
1966-01-04          0            0            0                 0                     0                 0                 0
1966-01-05          0            0            0                 0                     0                 0                 0
           Piancó.P_t Piancó.P_t_1 Piancó.P_t_2 Q_t_1 Q_t_2 Q_t_3
1966-01-01          0            0            0     0     0     0
1966-01-02          0            0            0     0     0     0
1966-01-03          0            0            0     0     0     0
1966-01-04          0            0            0     0     0     0
1966-01-05          0            0            0     0     0     0
```

My target data, first five rows:

```
> data[1:5,1]

                 Q_t
1966-01-01          0                    
1966-01-02          0                      
1966-01-03          0                     
1966-01-04          0            
1966-01-05          0
```

That was my code to define data:

```
# Scaling data for the NN
maxs <- apply(data, 2, max)
mins <- apply(data, 2, min)
scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))


# Train-test split
train_ <- scaled[1:train_days,]
test_ <- scaled[(train_days+1):nrow(data),]

X <- t(as.matrix(train_[,1]))
Y <- t(as.matrix(test_[,2:14]))

# Train model
model <- trainr(Y = Y,
                X = X,
                learningrate = 0.01,
                hidden_dim = 10,
                numepochs = 10)
```